# How to use eraser in corona?

Tags: coronasdk

In my application i draw the line and circle.how to erase the line.Using touch function to erase the line and circle.

Comment: I was also unable to find the erase function,  you can try to control its visibility by setting isVisible to false. Check [this](http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/objectisvisible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to remove objects on touch?

```
local function onTouch(event)    
    local object = event.target    
    object:removeSelf()   
    return true 
end 

object:addEventListener("touch",onTouch)
```

Answer (score 0):

object:removeSelf() will surely help you

Answer (score -1):

Try to place some objects with same color as that of your background.

Comment: Erasing is usually about removing rather than adding more objects. Each object adds to memory. With your approach, if too many erases are done, the whole thing will become slow or crash due to excessive memory usage.